# LVM RAID1 always rebuilds on boot — why?

Tags: linux, lvm

I have a Debian (Bookworm) NAS with software RAID1 that has an interesting problem: every boot, one of the RAID1 mirrors is flagged as dirty and has to rebuild. The other mirror is fine.

I have the following device mapper stack:

- 2 LUKS crypt + integrity (set up with LUKS2 `--integrity`) on physical disk partitions.
- Each encrypted volume is used as a physical volume in an LVM volume group.
- 2 RAID1 logical volumes (using LVM RAID1, not mirror).  The volumes are `home` at 500GB and mounted on `/home`, and `store` at 5TB mounted on `/store`.
- `activation_mode` is set to `complete` in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`
- The two partitions are configured identically in `/etc/fstab`: UUID-based identification, and `defaults,relatime,nofail` options.

The `home` RAID1 reliably needs to resync at boot, and the `store` RAID1 is fine.  Where might I start looking to understand why the `home` volume needs to resync every boot?

Comment: Check the SMART report of the disk to see if one of the disk is having errors,
`apt install smartmontools`, `smartctl --all /dev/sd?`